# ASP.NET MVC4 ActionLink displays "Index" in links

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Typically, an ActionLink that routes to the Index action of any controller will omit the "Index" in the link, i.e., `http://localhost:8080/Controller/id`.  In my case, I am trying to pass a string as an ID to the Index action of the Eta controller.  The code is as follows:

`@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Index", "Eta", new { id = item.Name }, null)`

The resulting link is coming out as: `http://localhost:8080/Eta/Index/some-input-string` instead of `http://localhost:8080/Eta/some-input-string`

This RouteConfig is exactly as it would be from File>New Project>MVC4 Application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including "Index" as the action in the URI is necessary because you are including route values in the string.

Without specifying the action, the route values would be interpreted as the action.

Eg:

```
http://localhost:8080/Etc/abc123
                       ^    ^
                Controller  |
                            |
                        Action (oops)
```

To you, `abc123` is a meaningful parameter. To the routing engine, it's an action.

Comment: Thanks!  Guess that's pretty obvious, when you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard route in MVC4 Template is {Controller}/{Action}/{id}, so you need to change it to {Controller}/{id} with default Action = "Index"

Comment: this is just not possible. how would the routing engine know the difference between an action called 1 and an id? you're blindly guessing and guessing wrong.

Comment: if the route configured as {controller}/{id} than second parameter will always be interpreted as {id}

Comment: then you will never hit /controller/action the 2nd param will ALWAYS be id

Comment: in the question, author trying to remove action from the link using "Index" as default. I showed him a way to do so. It may be wrong way, but I know nothing about his app, I just answered the question

Comment: ahhh. i think u misunderstood. OP wanted action to be ommitted for default only (as usually happens with default) but to have action included all other cases for all controllers. But, by your understanding it would've been the right answer.

Comment: i meant for **index** only.